# Is a restart of Mongo required after making a change to config file?

Tags: mongodb, config, restart

I am changing a 2 node DEV env to allow for TLS (preferSSL). I've changed the config file on both nodes accordingly. For this to take effect, is a restart required?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from the official [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/).

> You can configure mongod and mongos instances at startup using a configuration file.

Any changes to the configuration files that you want updated will require a reboot of the process.

Comment: Sounds like the doc doesn't explicitly answer this question. The doc doesn't quite say the restart is required, but I guess we'll assume that's what they mean?

Question: If a Mongo config file is changed, is a restart required? Doc: You can configure Mongo at startup by using a config file.

I guess the doc also implies "You can ONLY configure Mongo using a config file at startup."

Comment: I guess it depends how you read it, From my experience I have never seen any app/script that consumes environment/configuration files dynamically while running.   this is due to 2 reasons mainly, 1. is the app suppose to check every 1min if the configuration changes? 
2. usually configuration parameters have a large affect on the process, which files it loads, which DB's are being connected. to handle all this at run time would massively complicate the code.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that there is a way to reload the config files without having to do a shutdown/startup on your own.

From the [shared doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) from @Tom Slabbaert, command line calls will do it (tested):

> Use the Configuration File To configure mongod or mongos using a config file, specify the config file with the --config option or the -f option, as in the following examples:

> For example, the following uses mongod --config

> mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

> You can also use the -f alias to specify the configuration file, as in the following:
> mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf